# Why am I getting a warning message in Geolocator after downgrading Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocator

i accidently upgrade my flutter from version 3.3.7 to 3.10.2 and I downgraded my flutter version again, but a lot of my dependencies have error
one of them is geolocator
this it the error :

C:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\geolocator_android-3.2.1\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\geolocator\GeolocatorLocationService.java:134: warning: [deprecation] stopForeground(boolean) in Service has been deprecated
stopForeground(true);
^
error: warnings found and -Werror specified
C:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\geolocator_android-3.2.1\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\geolocator\permission\PermissionUtils.java:27: warning: [deprecation] getPackageInfo(String,int) in PackageManager has been deprecated
.getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
^

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':geolocator_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

i already upgraded or downgraded version of the dependecies

i already try to flutter clean

Comment: what is your geolocator version currently?

Comment: i use geolocator: ^8.0.1

Comment: i suggest you to use latest version geolocator: ^9.0.2

Comment: i already try it
i just got different error to update my kotlin